# How to override the controller for Symfony4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, sonata-admin

I want to override the tird-party bundle's `controller` in Symfony4.

in this [explanation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/override.html#controllers).

It says.

> If the controller is a service, see the next section on how to override it. Otherwise, define a new route + controller with the same path associated to the controller you want to override (and make sure that the new route is loaded before the bundle one).

---

What I want to do is to override this Controller.

`myapp/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Controller/CRUDController.php`

Now I make CRUDController.php in 
`myapp/src/Controller/CRUDController.php`

It doesn't work,, maybe of course though.

However, what should I do next???

---

Thanks to @DreamOn comment

I made the file myapp/src/Controller/CRUDController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as BaseCRUDController;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;


class CRUDController extends BaseCRUDController{
}
```

But, it doesn't work, I guess I should do some routing setting.

Normally `SonataAdmonBundle` is routed like this.

`routing.yml`

```
admin_area:
    resource: "@SonataAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/sonata_admin.xml"
    prefix: /admin

_sonata_admin:
    resource: .
    type: sonata_admin
    prefix: /admin
```

However Symfony4/3.4 recommend annotation routing.

It makes me confused.

How can I register/routing my Controller?

---

I use [this](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/cookbook/recipe_custom_action.html) instead, not override.

Answer (score 0):

Extend bundle controller. Add bundle controller as a base controller by:

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Controller\CRUDController as BaseCRUDController;

And make your CRUDController extends BaseCRUDController

Comment: I see. It's quite simple and clear. thank you very much.I miss understood the meaning of routing.

Comment: however, how to registering or routing??